# Problem Updating MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, updating

Today I installed MiKTeX on my PC then went to updated as recommended, but I am facing an error, can anyone help please ? Here is the error message [image]

here is the update log :

```
2017-02-26 17:03:56,937+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 17:13:38,524+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 17:13:46,090+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 21.14 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 17:13:46,308+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 17:13:46,324+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:13:46,823+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 17:13:46,838+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:13:47,166+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:13:47,260+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:13:47,260+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:13:54,607+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 17:13:54,623+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 17:13:54,888+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 17:13:54,888+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:14:38,085+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 17:17:24,860+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 17:17:24,860+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 17:17:29,165+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 37.22 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 17:17:29,399+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 17:17:29,415+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:17:29,930+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 17:17:29,930+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:17:30,179+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:17:30,226+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:17:30,226+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:17:37,418+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 17:17:37,433+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 17:17:37,698+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 17:17:37,698+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:49:29,534+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 17:53:37,943+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 17:53:37,943+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 17:53:37,943+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 17:53:37,943+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 17:53:37,958+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 17:53:37,958+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 17:53:37,958+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 17:53:41,187+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 49.68 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 17:53:41,406+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 17:53:41,437+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:53:41,952+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 17:53:41,952+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:53:42,217+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:53:42,264+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:53:42,264+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:53:49,627+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 17:53:49,643+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:53:49,877+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 18:00:35,083+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 18:03:53,742+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 18:03:53,743+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 18:03:53,743+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 18:03:53,744+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 18:03:53,744+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 18:03:53,752+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 18:03:53,755+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 18:03:56,704+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 54.40 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 18:03:56,922+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 18:03:56,938+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:03:57,437+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 18:03:57,453+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:03:57,702+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:03:57,749+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:03:57,749+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:04:05,034+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 18:04:05,050+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 18:04:05,300+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:04:05,300+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 18:04:05,300+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:04:05,300+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 18:35:09,447+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 18:40:57,080+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 18:42:02,225+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 2.46 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 18:42:02,475+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 18:42:02,491+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:42:02,990+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 18:42:03,005+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:42:03,255+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:42:03,302+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:42:03,302+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:42:10,634+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 18:42:10,649+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,915+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 18:42:10,915+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,915+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:03:56,937+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 17:06:21,394+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 17:07:55,383+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 17:13:38,508+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 17:13:38,524+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 17:13:46,090+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 21.14 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 17:13:46,308+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 17:13:46,324+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:13:46,823+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 17:13:46,838+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:13:47,166+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:13:47,260+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:13:47,260+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:13:54,607+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 17:13:54,623+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 17:13:54,872+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:13:54,888+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 17:13:54,888+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:13:54,888+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:14:38,085+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 17:17:24,844+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 17:17:24,860+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 17:17:24,860+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 17:17:29,165+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 37.22 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 17:17:29,399+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 17:17:29,415+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:17:29,930+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 17:17:29,930+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:17:30,179+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:17:30,226+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:17:30,226+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:17:37,418+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 17:17:37,433+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 17:17:37,683+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:17:37,698+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 17:17:37,698+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:17:37,698+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:49:29,534+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 17:53:37,943+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 17:53:37,943+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 17:53:37,943+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 17:53:37,943+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 17:53:37,958+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 17:53:37,958+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 17:53:37,958+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 17:53:41,187+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 49.68 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 17:53:41,406+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 17:53:41,437+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:53:41,952+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 17:53:41,952+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:53:42,217+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:53:42,264+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:53:42,264+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 17:53:49,627+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 17:53:49,643+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 17:53:49,877+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:53:49,877+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 17:53:49,877+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 17:53:49,892+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 18:00:35,083+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 18:03:53,742+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 18:03:53,743+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 18:03:53,743+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 18:03:53,744+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 18:03:53,744+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 18:03:53,752+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 18:03:53,755+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 18:03:56,704+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 54.40 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 18:03:56,922+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 18:03:56,938+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:03:57,437+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 18:03:57,453+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:03:57,702+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:03:57,749+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:03:57,749+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:04:05,034+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 18:04:05,050+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:04:05,284+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 18:04:05,300+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:04:05,300+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 18:04:05,300+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:04:05,300+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
2017-02-26 18:35:09,447+0200 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6236 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-02-26 18:40:57,064+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-02-26 18:40:57,080+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-02-26 18:42:02,225+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 163951 bytes, 2.46 KB/Sec
2017-02-26 18:42:02,475+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: cd0965ebbb7fa65525d4da14db258bf6
2017-02-26 18:42:02,491+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:42:02,990+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-02-26 18:42:03,005+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:42:03,255+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:42:03,302+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:42:03,302+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-02-26 18:42:10,634+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-02-26 18:42:10,649+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/toshiba/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-02-26 18:42:10,899+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,915+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-02-26 18:42:10,915+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-02-26 18:42:10,915+0200 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.
```

Comment: Have you closed all windows that use MikTeX (TeXworks or others) and killed all related processes? Sometimes that's enough.

Comment: @TeXnician I did and it still doesn't work, I've added the update log, it is long and ugly I don't know how to presented in a better shape.

Comment: Have you tried updating as admin before? If not you should.

Comment: Do you have a single user or a multiuser installation?

Comment: Installed it as multiuser, but my PC contains one user only

Comment: @TeXnician how do I update as admin ?

Comment: Start the update manager (admin).

Comment: It finally worked ! Thank you guys you're the best.